# Does anyone know of a non-trivial algebraic structure satisfying these four identities?

Tags: abstract-algebra, examples-counterexamples

Does anyone know of a non-trivial (i.e. cardinality $\geq 2)$ algebraic structure $(X,+,-)$ satisfying the following identities?

1. $(x+a)-a=x$
2. $(x-a)+a=x$
3. $(x+y)+a = (x+a)+(y+a)$
4. $(x-y)+a = (x+a)-(y+a)$

*Remark.* The Abelian group of order $2$ doesn't satisfy the last two conditions.

**Motivation.** I think its cool that if $X$ is such an algebraic structure, then for every $a \in X$, the functions $$x \mapsto x+a, \qquad x \mapsto x-a$$

are automorphism of $X$. This mean that if $a \in X$ and $f \in \mathrm{Aut}(X)$, then $f+a \in \mathrm{Aut}(X)$ and $f-a \in \mathrm{Aut}(X).$

Comment: can we take the free non-associative algebra on $X$ and then quotient out by the relations?

Comment: @JC574 : And how do you that it doesn't give a trivial structure?

Comment: well i don't, it was just an idea. That's why I left it as a comment and not an answer.

Comment: - Although it depends on what you define as trivial, for example then with this algebra we would have $x+a \neq x$ I think for at least some $x$ and $a$

Comment: This seems like something a proof assistant could construct for you.

Comment: Does $\,a\,$ denote a constant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of $+$ and $-$, let us use $\tilde{+}$ and $\tilde{-}$ as the algebraic operations
we wish to invent.

Let $\mathcal{D} = \{\; a + b \epsilon : a, b \in \mathbb{R} \;\}$ be the the set of 
[dual numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_number) over $\mathbb{R}$. i.e. 
the algebra extending $\mathbb{R}$ by adjoining one new element $\epsilon$ with the property
$\epsilon^2 = 0$. Now define binary operations $\tilde{+}$ and $\tilde{-}$ on $\mathcal{D}$ by

$$\begin{align}
( a + b\epsilon)\;\tilde{+}\;(c + d\epsilon ) &\;\stackrel{def}{=}
(a + b\epsilon) + (c + d\epsilon)\epsilon = a + (b + c)\epsilon\\
( a + b\epsilon)\;\tilde{-}\; (c + d\epsilon ) &\;\stackrel{def}{=}
(a + b\epsilon) - (c + d\epsilon)\epsilon = a + (b - c)\epsilon
\end{align}$$

It is easy to check

1. $(x \;\tilde{+}\; a) \;\tilde{-}\; a 
    = (x + a\epsilon) - a\epsilon = x$.
2. $(x \;\tilde{-}\; a) \;\tilde{+}\; a
    = (x - a\epsilon) + a\epsilon = x$.
3. $(x \;\tilde{+}\; y) \;\tilde{+}\; a = ( x + y\epsilon) + a\epsilon
      = ( x + a\epsilon ) + (y + a\epsilon)\epsilon
      = (x \;\tilde{+}\; a) \;\tilde{+}\; (y \;\tilde{+}\; a)$
4. $(x \;\tilde{-}\; y) \;\tilde{+}\; a = (x - y\epsilon) + a \epsilon
      = ( x + a\epsilon ) - ( y + a\epsilon)\epsilon
      = ( x \;\tilde{+}\; a ) \;\tilde{-}\; ( y \;\tilde{+} a )$

As a result, $( \mathcal{D}, \tilde{+}, \tilde{-} )$ is a non-trivial example for the
algebra structure you are seeking.

Answer (score 3):

A structure with these properties is called an involuntary [quandle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Racks_and_quandles), or kei. They arise as important algebraic invariants of knots. See [here](http://www.esotericka.org/cmc/quandles.html).

Comment: If I've understood the wikipedia article correctly, they're called [racks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Racks_and_quandles#Racks). A quandle is an idempotent rack.

Comment: @goblin Yes, precisely.

Answer (score 2):

Well I get one stupid example where $X$ is any set and $+$ and $-$ act trivially. What I mean by trivially is:

$x+a=x-a=x$ for all $x, a \in X$. Which is clearly not interesting.

Comment: True! **Corollary:** My definition of "non-trivial" was chosen badly.

Comment: Through some calculation I obtain $x+(x+x) = (x+x)$ is this OK for an algebraic structure??

Comment: That's an interesting result; how do you prove it?

Comment: (x-x)+x = x = (x+x) - (x+x). So 'add' x+x to the both side

Comment: Right, so we get $((x-x)+x)+(x+x) = x+x$, thus $x+(x+x)=x+x$. Very nice.

Comment: Having said that how do you obtain $x \rightarrow x-a$ is a homomorphism? ( I assume homomorphism in this setting would be (call a function f) f(x+y) = f(x) + f(y) and f(x-y)=f(x)-f(y)?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean by a homomorphism. To answer your question: I can't remember the proof, but if $f : X \rightarrow Y$ is a bijective homomorphism of algebraic structures, then so too is the corresponding inverse function. Hence since $x \mapsto x+a$ is a bijective homomorphism, so too is its inverse, namely $x \mapsto x-a$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16067/discussion-between-jack-yoon-and-goblin).

Comment: Hey I'm heading to bed soon; maybe we'll chat in the next few days though.

Comment: $x↦x+a$ being homomorphism is automatic consequence of 3,4 but $x↦x−a$ being homomorphism seem to require another one like 3,4 but with - instead of +. But maybe you can do more with axiom 3,4

Answer (score 1):

Below I will demonstrate that, if $+$ is associative, then $x+a = x$ and $x-a = x$ for all $x$ and $a$.  This is enough, I think, to qualify as a "trivial" algebraic structure, even though the underlying set can be as large as you like.

Beginning from (3):

\begin{align*}
(x+y)+a &= (x+a) + (y+a)\\
(x+y)+a &= ((x+a)+y) + a & \text{by associativity}\\
x+y &= (x+a)+y & \text{by (1)}\\
x &= x+a & \text{by (1)}
\end{align*}

Further, using (2) we find that $x = (x+a) - a = x - a$.